# Finding certain pattern in string, why the other matches?

Tags: python, regex

I want to isolate numbers in a string. These will come directly before and after a `/`

I have done this which is adequate:

```
a = "test0/0"
print re.split("(\d)/(\d)", a)
```

This has the required numbers in the output as expected, but why does test and also a blank entry get added to the output? and how do I avoid it. Here is what is printed:

```
['test','0','0','']
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ordinarily splitting on "0/0" would only get `['test', '']` back, but since your regex contains parentheses, the result also returns those captured elements.

> Split string by the occurrences of pattern. If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.

If you just want to capture the numbers and nothing else, try `re.search`.

```
import re
a = "test0/0"
print re.search("(\d)/(\d)", a).groups()
```

Result:

```
('0', '0')
```

Answer (score 1):

In your input `a` you have `test` at left side of `0/0` and having empty at right side. That's why you are getting an empty at the end after splitting.

Answer (score 1):

This is how `re.split` works [when you give it a capturing expression](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split). (A capturing expression is one containing parentheses that capture a certain part of the match.) It does the split, but it also returns the captured values. You only want the captured values; however. Given the specific input you gave, you could just do:

```
re.findall('\d', 'test0/0')
```

But if your input is more sophisticated, you may want to narrow this down a bit to digits around parentheses.

```
[d for d in s.split('/') for s in re.findall('\d/\d', a_string)]
```

In the latter case, even if `a_string` is '100 people like 8 test0/0' the result will still be `[0,0]`.